# Definition of product topology/box topology in terms of the Kuratowski closure operator?

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres, the definition of box topology is given in terms of open sets. I am wondering if there is a definition of the box topology/product topology in terms of the Kuratowski closure operator? i.e. how do we define the kuratowski closure operator of $A \times B$ given those given on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: There is no simple formula for all subsets of the product, only the one for "rectangles".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}_{\square}}(A\times B)=\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}_\times}(A\times B)=\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}_0}(A)\times\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}_1}(B)$$
where $\mathcal{T}_{\square}$ is the box topology and $\mathcal{T}_\times$ is the product topology on $X\times Y$ and $\mathcal{T}_0$ is the topology on $X\supseteq A$ and $\mathcal{T}_1$ is the topology on $Y\supseteq B$.

Comment: If we have an infinite union, the box and product topology diverge. Which of the two retains this equation? i.e. if $I$ is an infinite set, do we retain $cl_{T_\times}(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I}cl_{T_\times}(A_i)$?

Comment: Wow, I sure misunderstood the question. I thought that $A$ and $B$ where two topological spaces, and the OP wanted to define the closure operator $\operatorname{Cl}:\mathcal P(A\times B)\to\mathcal P(A\times B)$ in terms of the closure operators of the spaces $A$ and $B$.

Comment: The equation still holds in the infinite case. The topologies are different to be sure, but when restricted to calculating the closure of sets of the form $A\times\cdots\times B$, then they are the same.

Comment: If you are asking how to define $\mathrm{Cl}_{\mathcal{T}_\square}$ on general sets, then my answer would not be sufficient. I understood $A$ and $B$ to be subsets of topological spaces (to address bof).

Comment: I'm sure you understood the question correctly, seeing as the OP accepted your answer. I was misled by the OP's statement "I am wondering if there is a definition of the box topology/product topology in terms of the Kuratowski closure operator?" I don't see how defining the closure of a rectangle would help with that, but I'm just an innocent bystander.

Comment: @bof, I think once you have the closure of a rectangle, the rest follows, no? because the rectangles are a basis for a topology.